# Bootstrap 4 popover в заголовке таблицы. При скрытии исчезает весь элемент

Tags: bootstrap, joomla3, popover

Добрый день.

Имеем проект на **Joomla 3** c **Bootstrap 4** и компонентом **ContentBuilder**.

**ContentBuilder** строит таблицу `<table>`, **Joomla** приделывает к нему сортировку и подсказки в заголовках, получается что-то вроде такого:

```
<th class="sectiontableheader">
    <a href="#" onclick="Joomla.tableOrdering('col250','asc','');return false;"
        class="hasPopover" title="" data-content="Нажмите для сортировки по этому столбцу"
        data-placement="top" data-original-title="Наименование объекта">
    Наименование объекта
    </a>
</th>
```

Но после наведения на ссылку, когда подсказка пропадает, вместе с ней скрывается и весь элемент:

```
<th class="sectiontableheader">
    <a href="#" onclick="Joomla.tableOrdering('col250','asc','');return false;"
        class="hasPopover" title="" data-content="Нажмите для сортировки по этому столбцу"
        data-placement="top" data-original-title="Наименование объекта"
        style="display: none;">
    Наименование объекта
    </a>
</th>
```

*Break on...* говорит, что это делает **Bootstrap**.

Как с этим бороться? Что вообще может вызвать такое поведение? Куда смотреть?